# mysql insert on duplicate key related deadlock

Tags: mysql

In logs I have deadlocks that are related to this query:

```
INSERT INTO `driver_state` (id, state)
  VALUES('83799','waiting')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
  state = IF(state = 'active', state, VALUES(state));
```

Exact error:

```
ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I have tried to reason and understand how this query could even possibly cause a deadlock, but haven't gotten very far.

Table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `driver_state` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `state` enum('inactive','waiting_orders','has_order','busy') DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In this case we use MEMORY table, but with InnoDB it has same locking issues.

Table gets lots of these insert on duplicate key queries and select queries (All select queries are very fast and optimized). Transactions are not used anywhere nor manual locking etc.

Could you please propose any ideas what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score -2):

Why is there an IF statement in your ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

I think your problem is there. It looks like you are saying if there is a duplicate key, set the value of state depending on what the value of state is.

What is wrong with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE state='waiting'?

I would try this to see if the deadlock goes away to confirm that it is caused by the IF.

I would also explain here in greater detail what you are trying to do.